# Mocking time in Tokio

Tags: rust, time, mocking, rust-tokio

I need to mock time and luckily Tokio has such functionality with [`tokio::time::pause`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.pause.html) and [`tokio::time::advance`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.advance.html). I am trying to make sense of it, but it is proving slughly more difficult than I expected. Have a look at the following very simple snippet

```rust
use tokio::time;
use tokio::time::{Instant, Duration};

#[tokio::test(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn pause_time() {
    time::pause();
    let i0 = Instant::now();
    time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
    let i1 = Instant::now();
    println!("{:?}", i1-i0);
}
```

according to the docs

> pub fn pause()
>
> Pauses time.
>
> The current value of Instant::now() is saved and all subsequent calls to Instant::now() will return the saved value. The saved value can be changed by advance or by the time auto-advancing once the runtime has no work to do. This only affects the Instant type in Tokio, and the Instant in std continues to work as normal.

So I would expect my test to hang forever, however it completes instantly printing 10.001 s. What am I missing?

Comment: Youre probably missing the bit about auto-advancing once the runtime has no work to do. It's right there in the documentation you cited.

Comment: Also, if you read the rest of the documentation of `pause`, there is a [section](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.pause.html#auto-advance) that explains more in details the behavior that you are witnessing. TL;DR it's what @cafce25 said.

Comment: this is so embarassing. I did not read the last sentence. thanks.